# Mini cart should open automatically and close after few seconds when product is added in Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, mini-cart

I am working on **magento1** project. I want a solution to below mentioned problem.

When we add product to the basket, the mini cart should automatically open up and then close after few seconds(5 seconds).

How to do that?

please help me.

Comment: What extension are you using? Is it rwd's default or any other extension? Are you using any ajaxcart module?

Comment: I am using ajax cart

Comment: You need to find out the ajax call and on success you need to open the mincart and use setTimeout function to autohide the minicart after few seconds.

Comment: yes I did that.But cart is not opened.when click "add to basket button" page is refreshed and items are added into mini cart.But not opened

Comment: @suresh you can't use ajax because if you are using the ajax cart call. try to use session.